# How to display two-rows bracket in Latex?

Tags: latex

Does anyone know how to modify the following string in order to display the two-lines bracket?

```
str = '$$c_i =\{\begin{array}{l l} 1  \quad L\left(Q_i\right) < 0 \\ 0 \quad L\left(Q_i\right) \geq 0 \\ \end{array}$$';
```

The current output is the following:

[image]

The sign '{' has to embrace both rows (1 and 0).

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try superuser.com.

Comment: there are 973 questions on latex.. I don't think he is off topic.

Comment: For displayed math, better use \\[ ... \\] rather than $$ ... $$.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$$c_i =\begin{cases} 1 & L\left(Q_i\right) < 0 \\
                     0 &  L\left(Q_i\right) \geq 0
       \end{cases}$$
```

[image]

The tex file should have `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble.

Comment: I have tried to use the suggested string but it doesn't work. I am using it in Matlab text() function btw but I think it's not the case of Matlab.

Comment: Your document must have \usepackage{amsmath} in the preamble to use cases. I thought array was in amsmath also (its not), so i didn't mention it.
Output should look like this:
http://quicklatex.com/cache/ql_35c820f1064bb80a3d501080c0e8eec3.gif

Comment: If you can't get that to work, try putting `\left\{` before the array, and `\right.` afterwards.  The `\left` and `\right` commands size delimiters appropriately for what's in the middle, and the `.` is an invisible delimiter.

Comment: A double `\\ ` instead of single, to separate the two formula worked better for me, without the need for the `\usepackage{amsmath}`. I'm using Doxygen and MathJAX which may be why, although Brent answer uses two backslashes too...

Answer (score 16):

This is derived from Niall Murphy's answer, "tidied up" a bit:

```
\[
c_i =
\begin{cases} 
1 & L (Q_i) < 0 \\ 
0 & L (Q_i) \geq 0 
\end{cases}
\]
```

Note that the "\" becomes "\\", and I've removed the \left and \right parenthesis modifiers, which introduce unwanted (I think) space between L and (.

Answer (score 1):

Try add `\left` before `\{` and `\rigth.` at the end.

It should look like

`$$\alpha_t = \left \{ {{\sqrt{\frac1N},\; t = 0 } \atop {\sqrt{\frac2N},\; t \ne 0 }  } \right.$$`

or

`$$
\left\{\begin{tabular}{l} \textbf{Y} = 0,299\textbf{R} + 0,587\textbf{G} + 0,114\textbf{B} \\ \textbf{Cb} = 128 + 0,5\textbf{R} - 0,418688\textbf{G} - 0,081312\textbf{B} \\ \textbf{Cr} = 128 - 0,168736\textbf{R}  - 0,331264\textbf{G} - 0,53\textbf{B} \end{tabular} \right.
$$`